# Keyword Declaration

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

Asked to:

'Iterate through the staff nested inside the restaurant object, and add their names to the staffNames array.'

My solution keeps getting rejected with this error:

'Use a declaration keyword when declaring your key variable'

Feel like I'm going mad as I've definitely declared the variable.

Code below, what I added is in bold; the rest is the original code.

```
const restaurant = {
  tables: 32,
  staff: {
    chef: "Andy",
    waiter: "Bob",
    manager: "Charlie"
  },
  cuisine: "Italian",
  isOpen: true
};

const staffNames = []

**for (key in restaurant.staff){
  const value = restaurant.staff[key]
  staffNames.push(value)
}**
```

Comment: _"Feel like I'm going mad as I've definitely declared the variable."_ - no, you have not. You have just started _using_ it at some point, but there is no explicit _declaration_ of it anywhere. `for (var key in ...)`

Comment: `for (key` ... so, that's where you use one of the declaration keywords available to you in javascript - if you don't know what they are, you can search for "javascript declaration keywords" and et voila

Comment: @CBroe - `var` is so ecmascript 5

Comment: @CBroe yeah i got tunnel vision and just focused on value and forgot about key

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to declare the variable `key` in your for loop. Try this:

```
const restaurant = {
  tables: 32,
  staff: {
    chef: "Andy",
    waiter: "Bob",
    manager: "Charlie"
  },
  cuisine: "Italian",
  isOpen: true
};

const staffNames = [];

for (let key in restaurant.staff) {
  const name = restaurant.staff[key];
  staffNames.push(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I definitely had tunnel vision focusing on the value part and ignored the key

Answer (score -1):

> Feel like I'm going mad as I've definitely declared the variable.

You haven't. You've just started assigning values to it.

To declare a variable you need to use a keyword like `const` or `let` (or `var`, which isn't recommended these days, or a function declaration which wouldn't be appropriate here.)

```
for (let key in restaurant.staff){
```

---

Aside: Your code would probably be better written as:

```
const staffNames = Object.values(restaurant.staff);
```